# Building RDP into a C# app

Tags: c#, rdp

I'm currently trying to build RDP into an application that I've made. We constantly have to connect to many servers regularly and would like to eliminate the need for our employees to know the details to all the servers.

I'm currently trying to use the example at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx

When using the above I receive the error below:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {791FA017-2DE3-492E-ACC5-53C67A2B94D0} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

From this code:

```
MsRdpClient rdp1;
rdp1 = new MSTSCLib.MsRdpClient();
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: your missing a COM component.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different system than his(XP), the RDP has been upgraded since Vista and the COM registration is different. If you are using his binary directly, it won't find the COM Registration in your registry. You need to use the COM compoment registered on your computer.

Comment: I found that the MsRdpClient needed adding to the toolbox (Toolbox > right click > Choose Items). I then had to drag component onto the form rather than add it programmatically. This is now working. Thanks for your efforts guys!

Answer (score 1):

Set your Visual Studio project as x86 build.

Project Properties -> Build Tab -> Platform Target -> x86

[image]

If not helps than try to register com dll via [regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx).

Comment: compiling for x86 does not provide OS specific COM registrations.

Comment: But it does give you access to x86 COM components which are otherwise available in x64...

Comment: @nsr81 If OP used Add Reference dialog - the CLSIDs must be ok. In other case CLSIDs has compatible with later system versions.

Answer (score 0):

As iamsleepy commented, depeneding your OS, you need a different COM component.

The one you referenced, is specific to XP. Take a look at the following page for all CLSIDs for different operating systems:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For example, for windows 7, you need `{A9D7038D-B5ED-472E-9C47-94BEA90A5910}` which, if you search through registry (HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\CLSID), is provided by `C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll`